# Django template render html links does not works

Tags: javascript, django, python-3.x, django-templates, html-rendering

In my django project i have to rendere a var ina template as html.
I do this in my view:

```
con_stat = "<div id='overlay_demo' style='display:block'><div id='text-demo'><div class='login-box-body'><p class='login-box-msg'><strong><font color='red'>MY TITLE HERE</font></strong></p><br>My text here<br><br><div><form><button onclick='location.href=https://mywebsite.com/contact;' class='btn btn-block btn-danger btn-lg'>REPORT THE PROBLEM</button><br><a href='/register/retry'><button class='btn btn-block btn-success btn-lg'>RETRY THE REGISTRATION PROCES</button></a></form></div></div></div></div>"
context_dict = {'all_case': test_case, 'all_set': sg, 'the_stat': con_stat}
response = render(request, b_temp, context_dict, context)
```

well, at this point in my html template:

```
{% autoescape off %}{{ the_stat }}{% endautoescape %}
```

or also i try:

```
{{ the_stat|safe }}
```

template now display html correctly but the problem is the link, not my first button (with onclick= function) nor second one (with a href link) works.
In every case when i click the behaviour is to reload the same page.

Someone had experienced some problem related to link,javascript call in django template render like that above?

So many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
onclick="javascript:location.href='https://mywebsite.com/contact'"
```

Comment: Thanks but i cannot use "" and ' because i define my variable as a string " and inside i have only the option to use '.

Comment: I think there must be a way can escape double quote like `onclick=\"javascript:location.href` or some other way

Comment: javascript:location.href does  not work, i think the problem could be in |safe or autoescape with javacall or a link